# pagination not displaying on web page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

hi everyone i am having some problems in displaying my pagination for some reason the pagination dose not appear on the page can some one help me out here is my code :

**view**

```
<div>    


     <table border="1">


      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Second Name</th>
         <th>Phone</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Answer</th>
         <th>Comment</th>
     </tr>
      <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?> 
     <tr>

         <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->second_name; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->phone; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
          <td> <?php echo $row->answerA;?>
          <?php echo $row->answerB;?>
          <?php echo $row->answerC;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->comment;?><br></td>

     </tr>

      <?php endforeach; ?>

     </table>  
     <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>


   </div>
```

**controller**

```
 <?php

class Result_controller extends CI_Controller{

    function getall(){

   $this->load->model('result_model');
        $data['query'] = $this->result_model->result_getall();
        // print_r($data['query']); die();


        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Surva/index.php/result_controller/getall';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('tblanswers')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 1;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;


        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['records'] = $this->db->get('tblanswers', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(1, 0))->result_array();
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('result_view', $data);




        }
```

i used the codeigniter guide and also a tutorial that i found on nettuts any help will be greatly appreciated tnx in advance.

Comment: Have you tried : var_dump($data['pagination']); in the controller to see the desired output?

Comment: you have given two functions in your controller. Both are redirected into the same view. Can you explain us how you are processing this?

Comment: one function echos out the data in databse the other function is pagination.

Comment: Which one are you calling when the pagination isn't working? If your url is calling the pagination function make sure you're getting more than 10 results. What I usually do when setting up pagination is set per_page to 1 just to ensure it's working.

Comment: that's what i have right now i got hte pagination displayed on the page but it dose not work correctly it reads page 2 as page 1 and also it dose not turn the page ill update my code in my question have a look if u see something wrong.

Comment: i fixed the reading of page 2 as 1 but the pagination is not functioning for me at all an is not flipping  the pages.

Comment: Can you check whether you are passing the $query in the correct format using **echo "<pre>"; var_dump($query);**

Comment: what is the correct format? i passed the query and it returned an array for me size 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $limit = 10;

    $total = $this->legend_model->get_legend_count($language_id);

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'legend/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $total;
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;

    $config['first_link'] = '<< First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last >>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next ' . '&gt;';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&lt;' . ' Previous';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<span class="number">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</span>';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="current"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></span>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['offset'] = $offset;
    $data['legends'] = $this->legend_model->get_legend($language_id, $limit, $offset);

    $this->template->write('title', 'Legend : Manage Legend');
    $this->template->write_view('content', 'legend/index', $data);
    $this->template->render();
```